# Change my present website into secure web

Tags: security, web, subdomain

How can I turn my website into a secure website. I want it to run on secure webpage such as Facebook most apps run on secure page.

I want to know if I have to buy new domain or I can do with my same domain or if there is some setting to do so?

I have never worked with secure web.

Or if there is some good secure provider etc etc kindly tell me.

Comment: Thanks Aziz Shaikh for changing title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an SSL certificate. http://www.digicert.com/

If your using IIS, install the certificate to point to the directory where your web pages will be saved. And if you update all your links to https:\ that will make the user direction faster. No need for a different domain name.

When the viewer comes to your site, the browser will redirect to the ssl.

I can't help with apache or any of the other linux variants.

Comment: thanks for the help i will find a way to do job thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at an [Apache tutorial](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html) for SSL certificates. Setting up Apache locally, you can get to know certificates (generate your own, freely) and try deploying one.

It is possible to deploy a so-called self-signed SSL certificate online, but the user will be alerted that it is untrusted. What you pay for is the trust of a Certificate Authority, which in turn has paid the web browser to trust them. A "chain of trust".

Actually, some ISPs lack support for SSL(!) so that's good to establish beforehand.

Comment: Thanks Hennobal this will help me alot :)